# Windows 10 File History: How include other folders in backup?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I have had Windows 10 for some time and since using Windows 7, I really found the feature of Previous Versions useful.

Since transitioning to Windows 10, I have found that I cannot use the new File History (first introduced in Windows 8) on custom folders in the C: drive. I am only given the option to backup to external drive and the source directories are the Desktop, Libraries, Contacts and Favorites.

Can file history be configured to create snapshots on other folders other than the common folders provided above? Is there a way around this limitation in Windows 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Windows 10, there are actually two ways to do this:

- You can create a new library called "custom backup" and add your custom folders into that library. You have to show libraries first, which you do in Folder Options. They will show up in File Explorer's left pane after "This PC"). This is also possible in Windows 8.1.
- In Windows 10 you can use the Settings app (tooth wheel in Start menu). Go to "Update & Security" tile. Select "Backup" from the left pane. Click on "More options" hyperlink. There, you will eventually find a "+" button to add folders to the backup.

Personally I prefer method 1, because I immediately see which folders are additionally backed up by looking into my "custom backup" library. In method 2, I don't have a good overview but just a long list of folders.

Have a look here to see more detailed info: https://www.winhelp.us/file-history-in-windows-8.html