# File History on Windows 10 doesn't see my files, can't backup files

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, file-history

I'm trying to backup a Steam game's save files using File History on a fresh Windows 10. I'm using an external HDD to back it up. Windows is recognizing the drive, saying the backup feature is active, but when I click "Back up now" to manually do a backup, it successfully runs but doesn't really save anything, just says after that "Your data is not yet backed up", like it couldn't find any files at all.

I'm trying to backup a single folder inside "C:/Program Files x86/Steam/...", so I removed every other folder for which I'm already using a cloud service to backup. I added this folder in the settings app, and also followed [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1012174/150243), adding this folder to a new library, but nothing seems to work. Every time I run backup it simply doesn't do anything, and the current size of backup is 0 bytes.

## Here's the configuration I'm trying from inside the Settings app:

[image: Screenshot of the backup configuration]

---

## And here is the folder added to a new Windows Library:

[image: Custom folder added to a "Backup" Library]

How can I correctly configure this feature to back up this single folder?

Comment: File History is only able to back up your library folders, your desktop, your contacts and your favorites. If we put the Steam game's save files in the original library（ not the library that we new create） and then back up the library, can we successfully back up this data?

Comment: What do you mean "the original library"? The same games **are** in their original directory from Steam

Comment: “The original library” refers to the library that comes with windows.